# Getting Current Class's Name

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have the following class:

```
public class dlgBoughtNote : dlgSpecifyNone
{
    public com.jksb.reports.config.cases.BoughtNoteReport _ReportSource;

    public dlgBoughtNote()
    {
        btnPreview.Click += new EventHandler(Extended_LaunchReport);
        this.Text = "Bought Note Print";
    }

    protected override void InitReport()
    {
        _ReportSource = new com.jksb.reports.config.cases.BoughtNoteReport(null);
        ReportSourceName = _ReportSource;
    }
}
```

Technically, If I called the following constructor dlgBoughtNote()

```
public dlgBoughtNote()
{
    btnPreview.Click += new EventHandler(Extended_LaunchReport);
    this.Text = "Bought Note Print";
    MessageBox.Show(this.Name);
}
```

I should be getting the result as "dlgBoughtNote" but I'm getting as "dlgSpecifyNone". Is there any way I could get the current class's name other than the way I'm doing.

Comment: Do you need the name of the type of current class or the `Name` property of the current instance?

Comment: I need to get the Current class's name. I got it full filled by using `this.GetType().Name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of getting the name of the current class' is probably `this.GetType().Name`.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `GetType()` on `this` to get the type of the instance, and use the `Name` property of the type to get the current type's name.  Calling `this.GetType()` returns the type that was instantiated, not the type that defined the currently executing method, so calling it in a base class will give you the type of the derived child class that `this` was created from.

A little confusing... here's an example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string MyClassName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}

...

BaseClass a = new BaseClass();
BaseClass b = new DerivedClass();

Console.WriteLine("{0}", a.MyClassName()); // -> BaseClass
Console.WriteLine("{0}", b.MyClassName()); // -> DerivedClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You've never told us, what your `this.Name` is. However, if you need to get the runtime type name, then you may use any of the answers above. That's just:

```
this.GetType().Name
```

in any combination you like.

However, I suppose, what you tried to do, was to have a property, returning some certain value for any of the derived (or base) classes. Then you'd need to have at least a `protected virtual` property, that you'll need to override in each of the derived classes:

```
public class dlgSpecifyNone
{
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "dlgSpecifyNone";//anything here
        }
    }
}

public class dlgBoughtNote : dlgSpecifyNone
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "dlgBoughtNote";//anything here
        }
    }
}
```

But this is obviously unnecessary, if `this.GetType().Name` solves this very issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it, I use it for my logger all the time:

```
using System.Reflection;

//...

Type myVar = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
string name = myVar.Name;
```